# abort http request on change reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Every time when any change in input tag happens an HTTP request is sent. There is an onChange method is written in the input tag which calls Http request. But I don't want to call on every input I type. It should abort the Http request if input is entered after every 1 second.

Comment: Can you please show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty easily with react hooks,

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";


export default function App() {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("");
  const onInputChange = useCallback(e => setInputVal(e.target.value));

  useEffect(() => {
    const abortController = new window.AbortController();
    const signal = abortController.signal;
    fetch("https://api.github.com/users/octocat", { signal });
    return () => {
      if (signal && abortController.abort) {
        abortController.abort();
      }
    };
  }, [inputVal]);

  return <input type="text" value={inputVal} onChange={onInputChange} />;
}
```

abortController.abort will cancel your requests before calling your `useEffect`.

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-yalow-2j46o

In addition to that, you can define your own debouncer.

Look at network requests in the sandbox.

Comment: so when it will hit request, after user has done typing

Comment: is there a way to make this into a hook which is reuable? which excludes the input element